# Ionic error when run under VS2013 / multi-device-hybrid-apps

Tags: ionic-framework, ripple, visual-studio-cordova

I'm having trouble using Ionic with this new multi-device-hybrid-apps feature of VS2013.

When I start my app using Ripple (F5 in visual studio) I see the error:

```
Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar

We seem to be missing some stuff :(
```

**A little context...**

I've created the Ionic app using the `ionic start myApp blank` from the commandline which puts the *index.html* as well as other files into a *www* sub folder - the *config.xml* file is placed into the parent of *www*. Then I created a new vs project, using js codova template. The sln and jsproj files sit in the myApp folder. And I added the files keeping the Ionic folder structure.

[image]

I've noted that running ripple from the command line and starting it from the www path doesn't show the error.

```
cd .../myApp
ripple emulate --path www
```

but this does

```
cd .../myApp
ripple emulate --path .
```

Any advise on setting up the project in visual studio but keeping the ionic folder structure would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-Device Hybrid Apps currently does not support the project structure that you're trying to use.

As a workaround, you can move the content out of /www and into the root of the VS project. At build time the files will be placed back into /www behind the scenes and things should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your insight about project structure - you say the files will be placed back at build time, how does this happen? Is this automatic or do I need to implement special build rules?

Comment: At build time, VS automatically does this for you, so no extra build rules are required.

Comment: Right its just clicked - there's a sub folders **Bld\Debug** that has the right structure.

Comment: It would be good if there was a article that explained the Bld folder and what happens when you build your app. What gets copied where...

Comment: Were you able to fix that problem?
As the multi-device hybrid cordova stuff does not come with any styling - ionic seems to be a nice addon to make the look and feel more like a "real" phone app.

Answer (score 0):

Since as of March 2015 Visual Studio Tools for Cordova does not support the www folder, in order to support the same project both in VS IDE and in Ionic command line tools, you can 
* generate the project with ionic start ...
* add an index.html in the root folder containing something like

```
<body>
<script>
  window.location.href="www/index.html";
</script>
</body>
```

This way, Visual Studio will launch the Ripple emulator with the index.html in the root folder, which will then redirect to the contents in Ionic www folder.

The usual ionic cli commands such as ionic serve, ionic upload etc. will work this way.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer - I decided in the end to not use the Multi-Device Hybrid Apps project and instead just created a VS solution and added the www folder as a website. So I'm using VisualStudio as a text editor nothing more. To run the app I have a batch script which calls `ionic serve` plus some other setup things. This works well since I'm not tied into VS and because of the way the serve command auto-refreshes the browser.

Comment: Yeah makes sense, that's probably easier if MDHA is misbehaving